# Robot Framework Using PyCharm Editor:: Imported library 'class' contains no keywords

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I have created MyLibrary.py file with below code:

```
class MyClassNew:
    def hello(name):
     print "hello"

    def do_nothing(self):
        pass
```

I am trying to import file in other directory into same suit like below

```
*** Settings ***
Library  MyLibrary.MyClassNew

*** Test Cases ***
My Test
    Do Nothing
    Hello    world
```

but this doesnt work for me.

Comment: Please show the exact error message that you are getting.

Comment: Error in file 'C:\Users\knawate\PycharmProjects\MyDemo\Test\TestRun.robot': Importing test library 'MyLibrary.MyClassNew' failed: ImportError: No module named MyLibrary
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\libraries
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.0.1-py2.7.egg
  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\python27.zip
  C:\Python27\DLLs
  C:\Python27\lib
  C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
  C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
  C:\Python27
  .
  C:\Users\knawate\PycharmProjects\MyDemo    Message: No keyword with name 'Do Nothing' found.

Comment: Please don't put it in the comments -- it's impossible to read. Edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

The error "No keyword with name 'Do Nothing' found" is because of the earlier error "Importing test library 'MyLibrary.MyClassNew'".

Robot is unable to find the module `MyLibrary`. You need to put the folder that this library is in in your PYTHONPATH environment variable, or use the `--pythonpath` command line option to pybot.

This is all described in the robot framework user guide. See http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#pythonpath-jythonpath-and-ironpythonpath

Comment: i have tried with
 first run-> pybot -d Result --pythonpath Test/MyTest Test/Test.robot
 second run-> pybot -d Result --pythonpath MyTest Test/Test.robot
 third run -> pybot -d Result --pythonpath Test:MyTest Test/Test.robot
 fourth run -> pybot -d Result --pythonpath MyTest.py Test/Test.robot                                                                                           Folder Structure is -                                                                    -MyDemo
    -Test
      -MyTest.py
      -Test.robot

Comment: But it seems no success. Your help is highly appreciated.